# Querying by GlobalID in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, query, global-id

I can't figure out the syntax to query a feature class by  GlobalID because the GlobalID is not a string, float, etc.

What is the syntax to query by GlobalID in SQL using ArcGIS Pro?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE GLOBALID = {31595CF4-D5C7-49A4-85D2-C245BEBC009F}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually treat it like a string.

Note the selection Query statement made in ArcGIS Pro:

[image: select by attributes]

If you view the SQL statement, you see it wraps the value in single quotes:

[image: SQL statement]

Update your SQL to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE GLOBALID = '{31595CF4-D5C7-49A4-85D2-C245BEBC009F}'
```